# Unable to create form for reference model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the rails guide

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

In the example there is controller article and in its show.erb.html I am trying to add a form for comments

```
    <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
    <%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :body %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

But i get an error

undefined method `article_comments_path' for #<#:0x3a74498>

I am trying to learn rails , think its a small issue but cant figure it out

Comment: Please show your routes.rb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something is missing in your routes.rb file:

Your routes file should have this:

```
 resources :articles do
   resources :comments 
 end
```

Also, the relationship in your models should be:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments
end

class Comment< ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :article
end
```

Comment: I think the model part were okey on his code. so only the route parts was important to take care of. If model part was not okey, he must get error while building the association in the form.

Comment: Agreed :). I added info on models to make sure it wasn't a issue in there..since much info was not available about routes.rb.

Answer (score 2):

in your route file make sure you have the following:

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

I think, this is the only thing to help you with this problem.